# How do I convert Object to Integer in Servlet using getAttribute method?

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, jdbc

```
String id = req.getSession().getAttribute("user_id").toString();
    int user_id=Integer.parseInt(id);
```

The error :

Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(String)" is null

I have also tried

```
String id = (String)req.getSession().getAttribute("user_id");
    int user_id=Integer.parseInt(id);
```

The error:

class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: The attribute is not set

Answer (score 0):

It seems the attribute is either an `Integer` value or is `null`.

Try something like the following:

```java
Integer id = (Integer)req.getSession().getAttribute("user_id");
if (id != null) {
    int user_id = id;
    // code that uses user_id ...
}
else {
    // handle the case that there is no user ID.
}
```